# What is the process to diagnose transaction execution problems?

Tags: go-ethereum

In my private net the transactions periodically get stuck and I have no idea why. So, I am seeking a debug process to diagnose what could be wrong with a transaction. What would be the steps/functions to execute/call to trace what happens to a transaction?

For example, I submitted a transaction 1 hour ago, it is still pending but miners mine 1 block every 10 seconds with 0 transactions. I checked if this transaction has propagated to other nodes and on the nodes I own it is. But I created a new node, initialized genesis, downloaded the full blockchain and the transaction is NOT there. Why did it not propagate ? I can not get into the nodes that are mining because I don't own them, so how would I diagnose this problem?

This is how the tranaction looks like when I query it:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0x1ad26f1863aaa2b3920c6ed5729483e63b2f24ec3617b1957c73db88086bc4d2")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x986c12b8497a0a31055c1e67a98f629748d28151",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 18000000000,
  hash: "0x1ad25f1863aaa2b3920c6ed5729483e63b2f24ec3617b1957c73db88086bc4a2",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 11,
  r: "0x882c6392c7c95557ac7eb467a66e8e8e90c7d431ea7e001cd341a45b08a3b514",
  s: "0x121ca55d4523070403ff2dcf182311bbec30653de04d336b6306a84fa3cb2063",
  to: "0xab8758481b7c64f3428f872daa5cf889d9dd930f",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1f6",
  value: 100000000000000000000
}
>
```

the node is in mining mode, but it doesn't have enough hashing power to process it.